# How to prevent unintended equation number shiftwhen using tcolorbox with algorithm?

Tags: math-mode, equations, tcolorbox, algorithms, highlighting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,249,227}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt]
   Then compute
   \begin{equation}
       a= b + c
   \end{equation}  \end{tcolorbox}
   }{ 
   Compute
      \begin{equation}  d = e + f \end{equation} 
  }
 }
 \caption{My Code}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Here I have a simple piece of code which performs text highlighting.

However, an unfortunate side effect is that it stretches the equation number beyond the algorithm box (into the margins.)
[image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Also note the unintended indentation of the text.

Comment: Try something like `\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,width=\hsize, grow to left by=2mm,left*=0mm, grow to right by=2mm,right*=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]`.

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that the text *Then compute* is shifted too is annoying by itself. I'd rather want to have all the texts at the same level. Hence, I'll insert the *else* content into another `tcolorbox`, but with transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the width of the boxes, and fortunately algorithm2e stores the current indentation in `\skiptotal`.  The `tcolorbox` also has some internal margins that in the current setting are `4mm`.  Using these values we get

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{255,249,227}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\tracingoutput=1

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced
     jigsaw,colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,width=\textwidth-\skiptotal-4mm]
   Then compute
   \begin{equation}
       a= b + c
   \end{equation}  \end{tcolorbox}
   }{
   Compute
      \begin{equation}  d = e + f \end{equation}
      }
   \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced
     jigsaw,colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,width=\textwidth-\skiptotal-4mm]
   Then compute
   \begin{equation}
       a= b + c
   \end{equation}  \end{tcolorbox}
 }
   \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced
     jigsaw,colback=bg,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,width=\textwidth-\skiptotal-4mm]
   Then compute
   \begin{equation}
       a= b + c
   \end{equation}  \end{tcolorbox}
 \caption{My Code}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```